# Опрос через бота, aiogram, когда админ создает опрос, бот пересылает его всем подписчикам

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["pool"])
async def cmd_pool(message: types.Message):
    poll_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    poll_keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Создать викторину",
                                           request_poll=types.KeyboardButtonPollType(type=types.PollType.REGULAR)))
    poll_keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton(text="Отмена"))
    await message.answer("Нажмите на кнопку ниже и создайте викторину!", reply_markup=poll_keyboard)

# handler на текстовое сообщение с текстом “Отмена”
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Отмена")
async def action_cancel(message: types.Message):
    remove_keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    await message.answer("Действие отменено. Введите /pool, чтобы начать заново.", reply_markup=remove_keyboard)
```

Вот тут он создает, но не пересылает. Как сделать? или так или когда админ просто отправляет опрос он пересылает всем подписчикам

Answer (score 0):

Если он должен отправлять подписчикам чат-бота, то нужно сначала создать базу данных подписчиков (с юзернеймом и id) чата и отправлять созданный админом опрос всему списку БД по id.